# Optimize mean outer products

Tags: performance, numpy, optimization, matrix, eigenvalue

I am currently writing a short program to carry out some analysis of random matrix eigenvalue distributions but the parameter choice required for my analysis turned out making the whole thing extremely slow. Basically I should be looping over the function below, ideally for approx 5000 times, and eventually collecting the complete list of eigenvalues at the end.

```
C = np.zeros((N,N))
time_series = np.random.normal(mu,sigma,  (N + B*(M-1))    )

for k in range(int(M)):
    C += np.outer(time_series[k*B : (N) + k*B], time_series[k*B : (N) + k*B])
C = C/M

eg_v = np.linalg.eigvalsh(C)
```

where I need N = 1000, B around 10, M = 100.
However, with this choice of parameters the program takes something like 4-5 hours to run on my quite-performing laptop.

Leaving hardware limitations aside, is there something I can do with respect to the code to speed the whole thing up?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the loop with a vectorized solution using [`np.tensordot`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html)

Thus, the following -

```
C = np.zeros((N,N))
for k in range(int(M)):
    C += np.outer(time_series[k*B : (N) + k*B], time_series[k*B : (N) + k*B])
```

could be replaced by -

```
# Get the starting indices for each iteration
idx = (np.arange(M)*B)[:,None] + np.arange(N)

# Get the range of indices across all iterations as a 2D array and index 
# time_series with it to give us "time_series[k*B : (N) + k*B]" equivalent  
time_idx = time_series[idx]

# Use broadcasting to perform summation accumulation
C = np.tensordot(time_idx,time_idx,axes=([0],[0]))
```

The `tensordot` could be replaced by a simple dot-product :

```
C = time_idx.T.dot(time_idx)
```

**Runtime test**

Functions :

```
def original_app(time_series,B,N,M):
    C = np.zeros((N,N))
    for k in range(int(M)):
        C += np.outer(time_series[k*B : (N) + k*B], time_series[k*B : (N) + k*B])
    return C

def vectorized_app(time_series,B,N,M):
    idx = (np.arange(M)*B)[:,None] + np.arange(N)
    time_idx = time_series[idx]
    return np.tensordot(time_idx,time_idx,axes=([0],[0]))
```

Inputs :

```
In [115]: # Inputs
     ...: mu = 1.2
     ...: sigma = 0.5
     ...: N = 1000
     ...: M = 100
     ...: B = 10
     ...: time_series = np.random.normal(mu,sigma,  (N + B*(M-1))  )
     ...:
```

Timings :

```
In [116]: out1 = original_app(time_series,B,N,M)

In [117]: out2 = vectorized_app(time_series,B,N,M)

In [118]: np.allclose(out1,out2)
Out[118]: True

In [119]: %timeit original_app(time_series,B,N,M)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.56 s per loop

In [120]: %timeit vectorized_app(time_series,B,N,M)
10 loops, best of 3: 26.2 ms per loop
```

Thus, we are seeing a **`60x`** speedup for the inputs listed in the question!

Comment: This really made my day, thanks a lot. Modified code is running now and the speedup is evident.